# Meaning of "bobbed" in "hair bobbed from a ray of sunlight"

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context, past-tense

From [*The Assassination of Jesse James by the Coward Robert Ford*](http://www.quotefully.com/movie/The+Assassination+of+Jesse+James+by+the+Coward+Robert+Ford/Dick+Liddil):

> Ed Miller: I was with a girl once. Wasn't a squaw, but she was purty. She had yellow hair, like uh... oh, like something.
>   Dick Liddil: Like hair bobbed from a ray of sunlight?

What does *bobbed* mean in this context? I guess it means "cut", but I would like a native speaker to verify.

Comment: Still [general reference](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bob?q=bob#bob-2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To *bob* in terms of hair is to cut (from which *bob* the noun for a particular short style).

The suggestion is that if you were to take a ray of sunlight, and cut it into appropriate length to use as a wig, the result would be akin to this lady's hair.

Bad poetic metaphors often seem ridiculous when analysed like this, but in this case it is meant to be going overboard with the metaphor, as the speaker is making fun of the fact that the other speaker couldn't think of any comparison at all.